# How to keep timezone of dataframe index when inferring datetime format in pandas read csv function?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I am trying to read a csv file whose index is stored in a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS UTC` format. Here is an example of how a date is stored in the csv file :
`2018-11-19 13:32:00 UTC`

When reading the csv file, I am using `pandas.read_csv()`. This function has inbuilt parameters that infer the datetime of the index and this speeds up the process significantly.

However, when reading the csv file into a dataframe, the `UTC` timezone is dropped. Here is my code below:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('bitfinex_ENJ_USD_1m.csv',
                delimiter = ',',
                index_col = 'Date',
                engine = 'c',
                parse_dates = True,
                infer_datetime_format = True)
```

I have tried consulting the documentation, and whilst I could use `tz.localize` function, this would be expensive as this dataset is quite large and would involve manipulating an entire index to add information already present in the csv file. I was wondering is there a way where this timezone component can be kept explicitly whilst performing the `read_csv` function?

Comment: cannot reproduce (get I get datetime64[ns, UTC]) -> can you try with `parse_dates=['Date']`? Also, you don't need to set infer_datetime_format=True I think. Also, do you have to specify the engine?

Comment: Specifying engine increases the speed of reading the file by 3 times.

Comment: Ok so did you try my other suggestion? Another thing to keep in mind is that pandas internally handles unaware datetime as if it was UTC (in contrast to native Python, which assumes local time). So although in your case of course it *should* be parsed correctly, from a practical perspective, it's sort-of tolerable I think.

Comment: Yes I tried setting infer datetime format to False and now that seemed to do the trick. It removed UTC and replaced it with +00:00 which I suppose will do. Albeit this then the made runtime slower.

Comment: `+00:00` means UTC so this is expected. The column dtype should now be `datetime64[ns, UTC]`. Another option you could try is parsing with `utc=True`, see [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-csv-mixed-timezones). I doubt though that this will help performance.